how can I enabe fingerprint reader in ubuntu 24.04.01 lts version on lenovo L390?
After using all the commands to enable my fingerprint reader, as per my limit, i could not make it enable having same error again again
"Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available"
afte writing command- lsusb, i got this "Bus 001 Device 006: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. Metallica MOH Touch Fingerprint Reader"
i did'not find my device supported "ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics" on website lb fprint supported device

I would make sure fingerprint is enabled. Enter in terminal -  gsettings set org.gnome.login-screen.enable-fingerprint-authentication true - Or this may fix it. Add a needed line to fprintd.service  - Type in terminal - (Use nano or gedit) -
sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service and add:
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target  NOTE: I can't get this to format the entry should look like the PICTURE - -
...to the end of the file and save it.  Then run -  systemctl enable fprintd.service
There is also an app on GitHub if that doesn't work.
https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity?tab=readme-ov-file#enroll-a-new-user .. Good luck.
